# Find the best linear combination of two vectors resembling a third vector; implementing constraints

Tags: matlab

I have a vector z that I want to approximate by a linear combination of two other vectors (x,y) such that the residual of a*x+b*y and z is minimized. Also I want to keep one coefficient (a) positive for the fitting.
Any suggestions which command may help?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you didn't have a bound on one of the coefficients, your problem could have been viewed as multiple regression (solved in matlab by `regress`). Since one of the coefficients is bounded, you should use `lsqlin`. This function solves least squares problems with bounds or inequalities on the coefficients. Don't forget to include an all-ones intercept predictor if your signals are not centered.

I think that `fminsearch` would be an overshoot in this case, since `lsqlin` does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define a function, which desribes the cost. The lower the cost is, the better the solution. The output must be a single scalar, e.g. the norm of the difference.

To avoid negative values for x, add something like `(x<0)*inf`. This rejects every solution with a negative x.

If done so, use `fminsearch` for a numeric solution.